# Unit testing, IoC, DI and mocking objects within a WCF service

Tags: wcf, mocking, tdd, ninject, moq

I have a WCF service (INTWCF) that consumes another WCF service (EXTWCF). EXTWCF exposes 5 operations, will be hosted on an external app server (in a DMZ), and implements message and transport level security.

INTWCF will be hosted on an internal app server, does not implement any security, hosts two individual services with approx 30 operations - a number of which are called by the operations on EXTWCF (along with various other domain level applications), depending on various parameters passed in (EXTWCF contains simple logic to determine which operations on INTWCF should be called).

EXTWCF implements INTWCF using IoC and DI.

Using TDD, I would like to write my initial *unit* tests for the operations exposed on EXTWCF. I would therefore like to mock up INTWCF using Moq. I would have thought that I should mock up and inject INTWCF in to the unit testing project, but I've read (in quite a few places) that IoC and DI should not be used during unit testing due to the additional testing dependencies they introduce.

Am I being fed incorrect information, or is there another way to approach this problem? Is mocking appropriate for this situation? Seeing as though my unit tests will be accessing the operations on EXTWCF, they will not know about INTWCF. This seems to me to be a perfect case for DI?

I'm using Ninject for IoC and DI; if DI is the answer, does Ninject provide a bootstrapper / plugins for unit testing? I'm not familiar with any, and don't see anything on their web page?

Comment: As you allude to, you'll find no recommendations for mixing DI containers and (esp Unit) testing. There are auto mocking containers which are a whole different animal. Have a look at AutoFixture and AutoFixture.AutoMoq - it takes a little bit of getting used to but it's applicable to lots of testing scenarios (including but not limited to TDD). Other automocking containers are available though...

Comment: I was looking at this quite a bit today, and I came to the conclusion that I didn't need to use DI in the end; the EXTWCF implements INTWCF using Constructor Injection, so I can instantiate EXTWCF in my unit tests, and fake / stub the constructor injected dependencies (or mock them - not sure which to do yet). I'll take a look at AutoMoq and see if that gives me a bit more insight.